# MS Word Duplicate Page Numbering - same page number on facing pages for a manual

Tags: microsoft-word, duplicate, numbering

We use one document for both the trainer and trainee manuals. Trainer manuals include all pages, and the trainee manuals are printed from only the odd pages. It's a great solution for maintenance, but confusing for learners as their pages are numbered 3,5,7,9.... (We don't number the cover page.)

I was wondering if, starting on page 2 after the section break, we could duplicate the numbering for facing pages (i.e. 2,2,3,3,4,4....)

Comment: VBA Code perhaps (not one my skills). This is not a native feature of Word.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with somewhat complex computation fields. Note that this will not work with indices nor Tables of Contents. Word will continue to see its formatted page numbers rather than those generated by the computation fields.

You will need headers/footers set as [different even and add pages](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Odd_and_Even).
You would want your cover page inserted using the Insert > Pages > Cover Page function.

Instead of a Page field, you would want the following calculation field on the odd pages:

```
{ = { Page }/2 + .5 }
```

On the Even numbered pages you would want:

```
{ = { Page } / 2 }
```

See my writing on [page numbers](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers) and on [pagination fields](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Pagination) in Word.

By design, the facing pages would be 2 & 3, 4 & 5, etc.
That is, the even numbered page in a document is going to be on the left and the facing page would be the next odd-numbered page.

You may need to use the following for your even numbered pages.

```
{ = { Page } / 2 - 1 }
```

Note, **you cannot simply type field codes**. The {} braces must be generated in pairs by Word. See my article on [Dealing with Fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501).